# Execute a javascript from file on click button

Tags: javascript

I try to archive to execute a javascript from a file wish is located at assets/js/
but wen i click the button nothing happens.
I maybe do something wrong, i am new in javascript.
This is my code

```
<a href='linkhref.html' id='mylink'>view</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');

myLink.onclick = function(){

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "assets/js/post.js"; 
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
return false;

}


</script>
```

Inicial i have to try to do like this code below

```
<a class ="faux-button" href=<?php HTML :: page_js("post.js");?> target="_black">View</a>
```

But no success to

Comment: Check your network tab to see if the script path is correct.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Tank you for the replay i have verified and the path is correct i work in localhost for test proposes, in fact i have see the dot and removed but  i continue not obtain nothing from it

Comment: Check the network tab, make sure the script is loading. Make sure the script content is what you expect. Make sure that it does something you can monitor when it loads (such as logging something to the console). Check the DOM afterwards to make sure the script element is where you expect it to be.

Comment: Setting the `type` of a script is **not** recommended unless you are setting it to `module` or something that isn't JS. It defaults to JS so being explicit has no benefit, but does provide the opportunity to make a typo and and break it.

Comment: You have "." at the end of "assets/js/post.js."

Comment: @Quentin Tank you in advance, i have check and it give me an error the error is :assetsjspost.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: @lissettdm i have all ready remove the dot but i continue have that error

Comment: Clicking the link loads the page with `linkhref.html`. That `onclick` handler is useless without [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)